# How do I use typescript definitions when I can't import?

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I am trying to use moment type definitions with module set to "none", however whatever I do I get

```
error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'moment'.
```

In my tsconfig I have added "moment" to the types list (which contains and works for angularjs), and tried adding "node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts" to my includes, but neither works.

With logging turned on I can see that using the types it's loading the moment type definition:

```
======== Module name 'moment' was successfully resolved to 'C:/blah/node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts'. ========
```

The top of the moment definition has two global functions and a namespace:

```
declare function moment(inp?: moment.MomentInput, format?: moment.MomentFormatSpecification, strict?: boolean): moment.Moment;
declare function moment(inp?: moment.MomentInput, format?: moment.MomentFormatSpecification, language?: string, strict?: boolean): moment.Moment;

declare namespace moment {
...
```

Is there some special way I need to access these?